# Start an image slideshow on the click of a button

Tags: android, slideshow, android-intent

I have written the code to select a folder from the SDCard and its path is returned as a Uri/string. I also check if the returned folder contains images(ending with .jpg). Now that I have the path, I want to start a new activity(using intents and passing the value of uri in intent.putextras) on the onClick of a button so that the next activity displays images one after the other like a slideshow (using timers). Just give me basic outline as to how I go abt in doing this. What steps shd I follow?

Here is My Logcat Error :

> ```
> 11-10 17:23:30.500: DEBUG/dalvikvm(15114): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 49% free 2773K/5379K, external 11850K/13302K, paused 55ms  
> 11-10 17:23:30.510: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(15114): 3840000-byte external allocation too large for this process.  
> 11-10 17:23:30.510: ERROR/dalvikvm(15114): Out of memory: Heap Size=5379KB, Allocated=2774KB, Bitmap Size=11850KB, Limit=20480KB  
> 11-10 17:23:30.510: ERROR/dalvikvm(15114): Trim info: Footprint=5379KB, Allowed Footprint=5379KB, Trimmed=908KB  
> 11-10 17:23:30.510: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(15114): VM won't let us allocate 3840000 bytes  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: DEBUG/dalvikvm(15114): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 2773K/5379K, external 11850K/13302K, paused 34ms  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: DEBUG/skia(15114): --- decoder->decode returned false  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(15114): Shutting down VM  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: WARN/dalvikvm(15114): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)    
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=7299KB, Allocated=2773KB, Bitmap Size=11850KB)
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeFile(Native Method)
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:355)
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:433)
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at com.androidworkz.imageviewflipper.ImageViewFlipper$MyGestureDetector.onFling(ImageViewFlipper.java:357)
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:568)  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at com.androidworkz.imageviewflipper.ImageViewFlipper.onTouchEvent(ImageViewFlipper.java:428)  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2217)    
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1747)  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2336)  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1976)  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)   
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)  
> 11-10 17:23:30.550: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15114):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
> 11-10 17:23:30.570: WARN/ActivityManager(123):
> ```

Force finishing activity com.androidworkz.imageviewflipper/.ImageViewFlipper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello As you have Describe that you want to make Slide Show then You Should have to Use Android ViewFlipper To Make Slide Show as you require .Please Check This Reference Link Before Making Any Thing Like Slide Show of Images in android.

The Link one is use to best Thing to search almost all types of images path from SD Card but using this Example you will have to deal with Run Out of Memory in android so be careful to use it.In That Example Images are Slide By Using Swipe and after swipe much more time it will force close due to memory problem.

1.[Link One](http://androidworkz.com/2010/07/06/source-code-imageview-flipper-sd-card-scanner/)

in above example They are using

```
 viewFlipper.showNext();
 viewFlipper.showPrevious();
```

So you have to use your own logic to make ViewFlipper to Flip as Some Regular Interval 
For Making Now Slide Show Use Timer to Make ViewFlipper Next after some time as you like or may be use can Use Thread to make ViewFlipper Next.

and you can also apply animation at the time between changes from one image to other .
Here is Link for Animation Use in android :[Click here Link Two](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html)

You May also Face Memory Problem So read This Also :[Link Three](http://tech.favoritemedium.com/2011/07/viewflipper-and-bitmaps-in-android-30.html)

Comment: Edited the code to meet my requirements.. now like u said, stuck with the force close problem here after displaying some images continuously in a row.. working on it..

Comment: @Hello Are you Test You Application In Mobile and What is your android mobile RAM .

Comment: Yeah I tested the app on my mobile. It has 512 MB RAM.

Comment: Then it should Work Fine ,Use this thing to get Image from Path        mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImageList  .get(currentIndex));and set BitMap To Imageview iv.setImageBitmap(mBitmap); if still not work and we have to check what you get Error

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem has solved partially. But If I have images with higher resolution, the same problem persists. I've pasted the logcat and it says OutOfMemoryError! What else can be done?

Comment: @Yes Same Problem i face when image size are Big and Image are Much high Resolution. i am also Checking For Better Solution .

Comment: Actually when i work in the emulator(with high-res images), this error doesnt show up often. One solution which may help us according to the link three u mentioned is to use only 1 imageview instead of using three. Going to be trying that tomo. Kindly post here if u find a better soln and I will if I find one.